# Event handler for rasing notifications between classes is always null

Tags: c#, .net, events

in a service class I have a method at which end I want to raise an event that can be listened by other two services.

This is how I'm trying to do it. But my problem is that the null check for the handler is always true.

Inside the IProfileService file I define the delegate and the actual interface

```
public delegate void PersonDetailsUpdated(Person person, bool personDetailsWereUpdated);

public interface IProfileService
{
    void UpdateContactDetails(Person person);
    event PersonDetailsUpdated PersonDetailsUpdatedEvent;
}
```

And this is the instance of that interface

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    // ... Dealing with dependency injection

    public event PersonDetailsUpdated PersonDetailsUpdatedEvent;


    public void UpdateContactDetails(Person person)
    {
        //... Doing stuff

        //We raise an event
        var handler = PersonDetailsUpdatedEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(person, personDetailsWereUpdated);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now in the other two services I do this (I only put the code of one of them)

```
internal class CustomerSmsService : ICustomerSmsService
{
    private readonly IPersonDAL _personDal;
    // ... Other dependencies...

    public CustomerSmsService(IPersonDAL personDal, /* ... the other dependencies */            IProfileService profileService)
    {
        _personDal = personDal;

        //... Again the other dependencies

        profileService.PersonDetailsUpdatedEvent += (SendPhoneValidationCode);
    }

    //... Other methods

    // What I understand is the so called Listener
    public void SendPhoneValidationCode(Person person, bool personDetailsWereUpdated)
    {
        //Stuff
    }
}
```

Maybe the answer is obvious but haven't worked with events before and I'm finding it impossible to figure out or to find an example that is clear enough for me although there's quite a bunch of them. But they seem to have followed another approach.

Thanks

Comment: What is being passed in for the `profileService` argument of `CustomerSmsService`? Is it an instance of `ProfileService`?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `CustomerSmsService` constructor on the line where the event subscription takes place (the line with `+=`) and make sure that single line is definitely being executed. You could also add the following right after that line as a double-check: `profileService.PersonDetailsUpdatedEvent += (p, u) => Console.WriteLine("Event was fired!");` You should see something in the output window when the event fires off.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I am using ninect so it shiuld get the instance binded yes

Comment: I will try asap your suggestion @Steve as I had to leave the code for now

Comment: You may call `UpdateContactDetails` before `profileService.PersonDetailsUpdatedEvent += (SendPhoneValidationCode);`

Comment: @Steve  profileService.PersonDetailsUpdatedEvent += (SendPhoneValidationCode);
is being called many times, I presume once every time ninject needs an implementation of the interface of the ICustomerSmsService, but using yours suggestion and placing 
    profileService.PersonDetailsUpdatedEvent += (p, u) => Debug.Write("Event was fired!");
doesn't seem to produce any output.

Comment: @T.S I don't know how could I do that with the current code as that line is in the constructor of CustomerSmsService

Comment: Well, you need to debug and see

Comment: Thanks @T.S. I couldn't make it work so I raise the event from the Person domain class where instead from the service.